# (CMD) i want to do something after exit

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

So I made something with java and when I run it it just works.
When I type ingame /restart, my batch files closes(that's how i want it to be), but i want that after my batch closes it opens up again.
so it would be something like this:

```
@echo off
title WeLive4Pk
color 5d
java -Xmx1300m -cp data/CompiledFiles;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar; server.Server
exit
start 2.run.bat
```

But after the exit you can't do anything so I want to ask you.
How can I make it that it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `exit`. It is sounds that you do not need it if you want your batch file to continue working.